# Why elasticsearch search query (when you inspect)on date is different from kibana query on date?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I used date as a field in kibana as shown below to search documents and date is between Oct 15, 2022 @ 00:00:00.000 - Oct 16, 2022 @ 00:00:00.000
[image]

**why it is different from elasticsearch query when you inspect(as shown below)?**
[image]

Comment: Could you check your data view? Which date field selected as time field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elasticsearch all timestamps are stored in UTC timezone. Kibana by default translates timestamps into your local timezone. The interval you specified at the top is in your local timezone and this translates to the UTC timestamps shown in the query.

Comment: Also, you can see the same original timestamp in Kibana by expanding the log in Discover and switching to JSON format view.

Comment: @Ayush
is there any solution to match these timestamps? I face a problem in elasticsearch queries doesn't match to kibana output even though I know myself what is the scenario.

Comment: The only way I can suggest is to change your system TZ to UTC so you will see the logs and query for the logs in same timezone. 
If you have access Kibana advanced settings, then change the dateFormat:tz field, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html